# python using class param as self

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, manipulate

I'm new to python and I wonder, if is possible to make a single method to manipulate with all class attributes, like:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, dict1 = {"test": 0}, dict2 = {"another_test": 0}):
        self.dict1= dict1
        self.dict2 = dict2

    def vary_attr(self, attr, key, value):
        self.attr[key] += value

x = Test()
x.vary_attr('dict1', 'test', 3)
x.vary_attr('dict2', 'another_test', 6)

print(x.dict1)

# Wishful output:
# {'test': 3}
# {'another_test': 6}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but it is possible to make it work? Having one method and through that method manipulate with both attributes dict1 and dict2?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your use case is to first get the attribute which is dictionary, then make the necessary updates. You can use `getattr` to get the attribute then perform necessary operations.

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, dict1 = {"test": 0}, dict2 = {"another_test": 0}):
        self.dict1= dict1
        self.dict2 = dict2

    def vary_attr(self, attr, key, value):
        # get class attribute by attribute name attr
        _atr = getattr(self, attr)
        _atr.update({key: _atr.get(key, 0)+value})

x = Test()
x.vary_attr('dict1', 'test', 3)
x.vary_attr('dict2', 'another_test', 6)
# x.dict1, x.dict2
# ({'test': 6}, {'another_test': 6})
```

Note, your use case doesn't require to set the attribute dynamically cause `dict.update` is a mutable function, but for other use cases, you can use `setattr` and pass `self`, `attr`, and `value` as parameters.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, setattr() works with attributes, but not with dictionaries. Your example works, but I probably don't wanna use update(), because if I make a typo, update() adds it as a new item.. Anyway thank you very much, you answered my question!

Comment: @TichomírDuchaplný `setattr` works with dictionary too, it's just convenient to call `update` for dictionaries else you need to make an extra copy of the dictionary, make the necessary changes, and finally pass it to `setattr` which is just unnecessary processing and makes it less efficient

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Python and I didn't know that, but thank for clarify. I finally went with other approach and I hope, this way is ok: `getattr(self, attr)[key] += value`

Comment: Yeah that's okay but it will throw error in case the key doesn't exist so you may want to handle that error.

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior I was looking for, thx!